# Git Pull and Push

Tags: git, github

I am adding my directory a git repository using the following steps:

```
git init
git add hello_git.py
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/my_repo.git
```

Everything works fine until above but when I do `git pull` to get the `README` I initialized while I creating the `repo` I get the following error:

> fatal: remote error:    Repository not found.

I check other answers but none of them are working for me. I do have the `SSH` key successfully set up because when I do `ssh -T git@github.com` I get

> Hi dalalkrish! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
>   provide shell access.

Also, I can pull and push to another repository from another directory just fine. I'm not able to understand what is going on here. I'll much appreciate your help.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. If you want to put this in answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using undistinctly both the `SSH` and the `HTTP` protocols. If you are interested in using ssh keys you should use the ssh endpoint of your repository and not the HTTPS protocol one.

It would look something like `git@github.com:user/my_repo`. That should solve this problem.

Comment: So it worked the first time when I changed `git remote add origin https://github.com/user/my_repo.git` to `git@github.com:user/my_repo` as you mentioned but then I tried to push another commit it threw `fatal: 'orign' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Comment: Check using the command `git remote set-url` to set the repository endpoint. That should fix it. Then you can use `git remote -v` to see if it has been set properly.

Comment: So, I did that now and earlier from other answers but it is still throwing the same error. `git remote -v` prints `origin git@github:user/my_repo (fetch)
origin git@github.com:user/my_repo  (push)`.